# Strange C++ syntax: setting function output with some value

Tags: c++, pybind11

I was trying to get [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html) up and running, and I ran across some strange syntax:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring
    m.attr("the_answer") = 42;
    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

I figured that `PYBIND11_MODULE` is a macro, and that pybind11 should execute everything inside the code block to setup a Python module. However, the syntax at `m.doc() = ...` and `m.attr("the_answer") = 42` looks strange. The code does compile on my machine though. My question is, what are they and do they have a name?

Comment: I assume the function returns *references* to objects? And that the objects have an overloaded assignment operator? Have you checked the PyBind documentation to see what it says about these functions and what they return?

Comment: I never knew you can set it that way. Seems like your hunch is correct. Would you mind writing it out as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is returning references to objects. Check this example:

```cpp
class A {
private:
   int var;
public: 
   int& internal_var() { return var; }
};

...

A a;
a.internal_var() = 1;
```